# Relating the dimension of simple modules to their multiplicities.

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let A be a finite dimensional semisimple $k$-algebra, $k$ algebraically closed, and let $S_i$ be a simple module of A with dimension $n_i$. The multiplicity  of $S_i$, that is the number of simple submodules of A isomorphic to $S_i$, is equal to $n_i$. Artin-Wedderburn grants us this fact.

Is there a more elementary proof of this statement? I have had little progress trying to find one.

Comment: The multiplicity isn’t the number of simple submodules isomorphic to $S_i$. For example, if $A=k$ for an infinite filed $k$ then the muliplicity of $S=k$ in a two-dimensional vector space is two, but there are infinitely many one-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Ah right, this clears up a misunderstanding on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate $\text{Hom}_A(A,S_i)$ in two different ways.

On the one hand, it is isomorphic to $S_i$ as a vector space, so its dimension is $\text{dim }S_i$.

On the other hand, if $A\cong S_1^{n_1}\oplus\dots\oplus S_r^{n_r}$ then by Schur’s lemma its dimension is $n_i$.